# How can i get the radio button data with controller in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, controller, radio-button

I created a widget which is sending data via an API in json format, built with controllers such as ;

```
final quantNumberController = TextEditingController();
```

And i am getting value from controller ;

```
String quant = quantNumberController.text;
```

And i store the data in json format such as ;

```
var data = {'quant': quant}
```

My current text widget container structure is like ;

```
          Container(
              width: 280,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: quantNumberController,
                autocorrect: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter location'),
              )
          ),
```

I would like to get this data within radio button structure. Is it possible to get the data with controller like before i did, or how should i get the data to my result json file ?

I tried like this ;

```
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Location'),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('First value'),
                    leading: Radio(
                      value: Cap.Cap33,
                      groupValue: _capp,
                      onChanged: (Capp value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _capp = value;
                          capp = 'Cap33';
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Second value'),
                    leading: Radio(
                      value: Capp.Cap22,
                      groupValue: _capp,
                      onChanged: (Capp value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _capp = value;
                          capp = 'Cap22';
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Third value'),
                    leading: Radio(
                      value: Capp.Cap44,
                      groupValue: _capp,
                      onChanged: (Capp value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _capp = value;
                          capp = 'Cap44';
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ) ,
          ),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can define a function that takes a controller

```
widget myRadioButton(TextEditingController quantNumberController ){
                  return Radio(
                      value:quantNumberController.text
                      groupValue: _capp,
                      onChanged: (Capp value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _capp = value;
                          capp = 'Cap33';
                        });}
```

for using

```
Container(
  child:myRadioButton (quantNumberController:quantNumberController) 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable like "Location Value"
Syntax -

```
late String LocationValue = '';
```

before @override
Widget build(BuildContext context)

And then assign LocationValue on radio button on change attribute

```
onChanged: ((value) {
            LocationValue = 'cap33';
            setState(() {
            _value = value!;
            });
            }),
```